# Open existing Aura Component in VS Code

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforcedx, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

I am new in VS Code Salesforce extension and I would like to ask if any way exist to open and edit Aura Components from VS Code.

I already learned how to create new and deploy them and now need to edit too

**I would appreciate any solution/help.
Thank you!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello michant and welcome to the community!

I would recommend you to use the official SFDX Extensions in VS Code.

Following this module you can configure VS Code and connect to an existing org

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-vscode-salesforce

After configuring your vscode you can easily use the org browser (if you are using a sandbox) to retrieve metadata for the aura components directly to your computer.

https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/org-browser

You can then deploy to the target org just by right clicking the file in vscode and using the deploy this source option

Comment: Hello mnunezdm, and thank you for the Welcome!  The information you provided where very very useful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Bravo! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it.
Just need to retrieve the data from your org and deploy it again after editing.
I recommend using  [Force Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JohnAaronNelson.ForceCode) in order to retrieve and deploy components,
Add it as extension to your VS Code